# How do while loops and if statements work?

Tags: python

```
i=0
while(i<=20):  # it will print:0,2,4,6,8
    if(i%2==0):
        print(i)
    elif(i==9):
       break
    else:
       i += 1
       continue
    i+=1
```

First question: if I remove the second `1+=1`,it will print `0` endlessly, why? What exactly does `break`/`continue` do here?

Second question: I learned that when `if` meets its requirements,it will not keep running to the following `elif` and `else`, so when `i = 0`, it meets `i % 2 = even number`, so number `0` will be printed, the rest of following should not run, so how did the number get increased?

Comment: Your second question answers your first one.  If you remove the last `i += 1`, then `i` *won't* be increased, and it'll just endlessly print `0`.  If you leave that last statement, then, since that `i+=1` isn't inside the `if` block, so it increases `i` before looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you remove `i += 1`, at the first iteration, `i` is 0.  It gets to `if(i%2==0)`.  It finds `True`, so that `if` block is executed and it skips `elif` and `else`.  If you remove `i+=1`, `i` will still be 0 for the second iteration, and the same thing will happen, again and again and again...
- When `if` meets its requirements, it will skip `elif` and `else`, but `i+=1` is not in either the `elif` block or the `else` block.  The `if`, `elif`, and `else` go together, but what is after them gets executed unless a `break`, `continue`, `return`, or exception happens.  Your second `i+=1` is really not very helpful because the only time none of the things mentioned above happens is when `i%2==0`.  You can just remove the whole `else` block because `i += 1` will happen without it.

Comment: thank you senpai!i removed the else block and the continuate part and i finally understanded it,tho im still not sure what continuate does,but i understand what break does now,it ends the loop,so when the elif=9 meets true,break command will be executed and the loop will end!

Comment: @Z.Q: `continue` means to skip all of the code below and just go back to the beginning of the loop.  It won't reset any variables, but it just means we're done with this iteration of the loop.

Comment: i took your advices and changed the i value to 11 and the second i=+1 to i=+3 to test how continue works,and i finally completely understand it,the result is 12 16 20 as i expected,thank you so much senpai!!and thanks for this site,cant believe how amazing this site is!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Note first that **i** starts at 0, and we enter a *while* loop that keeps running as long as **i** is less than or equal to 20.

When **i** equals 9, the condition `i%2==0` is false, so it drops to the next *elif* which evaluates as true.  In this case the `break` keyword means to end the current looping structure (the *while*), so the loop ends.

Now imagine that **i** is an even number (it starts that way), the first *if* condition evaluates to true causing the value of **i** to print.  It now skips the next *elif* and the *else*, going to the bottom of the *while*; there **i** is incremented by 1 (causing it to now be odd).  Note that the increment at the bottom is not part of the final *else* as it is indented less.  As it is indented the same as the *if/elif/else*, it is on the same level and not part of that (it is part of the *while*).

When **i** is odd, the first *if* evaluates to false, and if it isn't 9, so does the *elif*, dropping us into the *else*.  Here **i** is incremented by one (making it even), and the `continue` means to skip the rest of the loop (the *while*) and go back to the beginning (skipping the `i+=1` at the bottom).

Thus what we see is

- **i**=0, print 0, add 1 to **i** (from end of while), go back to beginning (reached end of while)
- **i**=1, increase it to 2, go back to beginning (skipping rest)
- **i**=2, print 2, add 1 to **i** (from end of while), go back to beginning (reached end of while)
- **i**=3, increase it to 4, go back to beginning (skipping rest)
- **i**=4, print 4, add 1 to **i** (from end of while), go back to beginning (reached end of while)
- **i**=5, increase it to 6, go back to beginning (skipping rest)
- **i**=6, print 6, add 1 to **i** (from end of while), go back to beginning (reached end of while)
- **i**=7, increase it to 8, go back to beginning (skipping rest)
- **i**=8, print 8, add 1 to **i** (from end of while), go back to beginning (reached end of while)
- **i**=9, quit

If you remove that final `i+=1`, look at what happens when **i** is 0.  The step that changed it from 0 to 1 and allows us to move to the next condition above is that final statement.  Thus without that, we can't escape the **i**=0 condition, and when we go back to the beginning of the *while* loop, we are still at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that your i += 1 is in the scope of your while loop, so at the end of the loop it will always be executed. Thus, if you remove it then you get an infinite loop since no other place are you increasing your i.

Your first if is always hit initially since you initialized i to 0. Thus, unless you hit your second i += 1, you will never change your i.

What continue does, to the best of my knowledge, is skip the rest of the code body to the next iteration of the loop.

If I'm being too confusing, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For `break` and `continue` you should probably read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) :)

In short, but probably not sufficient:
`continue` exits the *current run* of the enclosing loop (the `for`), while the `break` exits the *whole loop*.

Your second question has a shorter answer:
you have indented blocks after the `if/elif/else` -- from there, only one gets executed. The code after than (which increases `i`) is on the same level with the `if`, so it will be run afterwards just like after any other statement...